# Get list of fields for History object via APEX

Tags: apex, schema

I need to dynamically retrieve the list of fields for history objects, whether it be Asset or Opportunity etc. I normally use the following code to retrieve these fields for standard and custom objects:

```
String SobjectApiName = 'Asset';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(SobjectApiName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

String apiNames = '';

for(String apiName : fieldMap.keyset())
{
    if(fieldMap.get(apiName).getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
        apiNames += apiName + ',';
    }
}

system.debug(apiNames);
```

But this does not work for History objects.

How can I retrieve the list of field api names for say, "AssetHistory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you collect the fields; you have a check `isUpdateable`; where you filter out the fields which are allowed to be updated by user.

As all fields on `*History` object (`AssetHistory` here) are read only, you do not see any fields in result.

Not sure what you are trying to do, removing `isUpdateable` condition will show you all the fields.